# KotterKnife - cannot use bindView(R.id.example_id) for some classes

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

I am getting the below error when trying to use KotterKnife - but only for some classes. What's going on?

```
e: /Users/user/dev/git/to14/android/src/main/kotlin/com.example/adapters/ChapterListAdapter.kt: (59, 34): Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.app.Dialog.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.support.v4.app.Fragment.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.app.Fragment.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.view.ViewGroup.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
public fun <T : android.view.View> android.app.Activity.bindView(id: kotlin.Int): kotlin.properties.ReadOnlyProperty<kotlin.Any, android.widget.TextView> defined in butterknife
```

Comment: Zak, did the answer below help?  if not, can you add more information so we know if this is resolved or should keep looking for answers?

Answer (score 5):

Kotterknife's `bindView` delegate will work only on sublclasses of `Activity`, `Dialog`, `ViewGroup`, `Fragment`, the support library `Fragment`, and recycler view's `ViewHolder`. I guess you're trying to bind view as property of `ListAdapter`, but to have it work you'll have to have object on which you could call `findViewById`.

For non-RecyclerView `ViewHolder` you can try

```
class ViewHolder(view: View) { 
    val textView: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView 
}
```